# Bounding error of Taylor series (mixed exponential/product terms)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

For a homework problem in numerical analysis and scientific computing, I need to

- derive the Taylor series of $f: x \mapsto \ln(x+1)$ about $x=0$,
- find the smallest $n$ such that the error in $\ln(1.5) < 10^{-8}$, and
- find the number of terms necessary so that the error in $\ln(1.6) \le 10^{-10}$

---

I was fairly easily able to derive

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k + E_n(x)$$

with

$$E_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)(c+1)^n}x^{n+1}$$ for some $c: 0 < c < x$.

Further, I know that for $x < 1$, the bounds on $c$ imply

$$|E_n(x)| < \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

The issue arises when I try to compute the necessary terms for a given error bound: for $x = 0.5$, I need to solve

$$2^{n+1}(n+1) > 10^8$$

By inspection, $n > 22$ works. But I can't show that from the equation; I can only loosen the bound ($2^{n+1}(n+1) > 2^{n+1}$) and get $n > 26$.

Similarly, for $x=0.6$, I end up needing to solve

$$\frac{n+1}{0.6^{n+1}} > 10^{10}$$

Inspection again yields $n > 36$ suffices, but I can only bound to $n > \left\lceil{\frac{10\ln(10)}{\ln(5) - \ln(3)}}\right\rceil - 1 = 45$!

---

What strategies are there to solve these kinds of mixed exponetial inequalities? The textbook presents only a simplified error-bound problem, where this issue never arrises.

Comment: Inspection isn't bad. Especially if you do a binary search instead of trying all $n$ until you found the first that works. But for a simple situation like here, you can quickly get close to the smallest $n$ by making an adjustment step from the crude $x^{n+1} < c$. In your first example, you found $2^{26} < 10^8 < 2^{26+1}$. Thus the $(n+1)$ factor will be about $20$, which is between $2^4$ and $2^5$, and the smallest $n$ will be $26-4$ or $26-5$ (the former is the correct one). Similarly for the second, the $(n+1)$ factor will be around $40$, so $n \approx 45-k$ where $0.6^k \approx 1/40$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have $$|E_n(x)| < \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ you want to solve for $n$
$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\leq 10^{-k}\implies n+1 \geq x^{n+1} \,10^k$$ There is an explicit solution
$$n \geq -1-\frac{W\left(-10^k \log (x)\right)}{\log (x)}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Since $x<1$, the argument is quite large and you can approximate it using
$$W(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

- For the first case, this will give, as a real, $n=21.11$ so $n=22$.
- For he second case, this will give, as a real, $n=36.96$ so $n=37$.

However, what @Daniel Fischer proposed as a method is much simpler (clever inspection).

Comment: Well, this explains why i couldn’t find the analytical solution—a bit beyond my studies :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. It does not matter ! Now, you heard about Lambert function (which is just fascinating). Just remember that any equation which can write or rewrite as $A+B x+C\log(Dx+E)=0$ has an explicit solution. On the search bar, just type *Lambert* and you will see 3272 entries. Cheers and good luck in your studies. Cheers :-)